# JQuery compare class names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure what I've done wrong in this. I have assigned classes dynamically to rows. These classes are ordered and a row can have the same class. I want to order all the classes with multiple of the same identifier one colour. Then the next set of numbers an alternative colour before going back to the original colour. The last row always seems to fail though.

```
<body>
<table>
<thead>Row</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="a-1"><td>A1 row</td></tr>
<tr class="a-2"><td>A2 row</td></tr> 
<tr class="a-2"><td>A2 row</td></tr> 
<tr class="a-2"><td>A2 row</td></tr> // should have class warning,but doesn't after js
<tr class="a-3"><td>A3 row</td></tr>
<tr class="a-4"><td>A4 row</td></tr>
<tr class="a-4"><td>A4 row</td></tr>
<tr class="a-4"><td>A4 row</td></tr>
<tr class="a-4"><td>A4 row</td></tr> // should have class warning,but doesn't after js
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

**JQuery**

```
var flag = true;
$("table tr[class^='a-']").each(function(){
    var current = $(this);
    if((current.attr("class") == current.next().attr("class")) ||    (current.attr("class") == current.prev().attr("class"))){
        if(flag){
          current.addClass("info");
        } else {
          current.addClass("warning");
        }
    } else {
        if(flag){
          flag = false;
        } else {
          flag = true;
        }
    }
});
```

I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1skaLam/) to show my problem

Comment: which ones will have class info ?

Comment: yes for the last row it does not work,because by the time it comes to last row,prev row has warning class and it has no next row

Comment: you are just checking with attr('class'), it returns string of classnames

Comment: use it hasClass jQuery

Comment: @Geeky I had assumed that it was something to do with me adding a class, but didn't know about the `hasClass` method. I'm assuming that's correct. So you should add it as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: @jonny is possible that you put the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var flag = true;
  $("table tr[class^='a-']").each(function() {
  
    var current = $(this);
    var next = current.next();
    var prev = current.prev();

    var currentClassName = $(this).attr('class');
   // alert(currentClassName);
   if(next.hasClass(currentClassName) || prev.hasClass(currentClassName))
   {
      if(flag){
          current.addClass("info");
        } else {
          current.addClass("warning");
        }
   }
     else {
        if(flag){
          flag = false;
        } else {
          flag = true;
        }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.info{background-color: blue;}
.warning{background-color: yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>Row</thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="a-1">
        <td>A1 row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="a-2">
        <td>A2 row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="a-2">
        <td>A2 row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="a-2">
        <td>A2 row</td>
      </tr>// should have class warning,but doesn't after js
      <tr class="a-3">
        <td>A3 row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="a-4">
        <td>A4 row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="a-4">
        <td>A4 row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="a-4">
        <td>A4 row</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="a-4">
        <td>A4 row</td>
      </tr>// should have class warning,but doesn't after js
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This part of condition was never fullfiled:

```
(current.attr("class") == current.prev().attr("class")
```

because when you added class "warning" or "info" to it, so even if it contains the same class as current element, it has additional class and it's not equal. So it's better, write something like that:

```
 var currClassName = "warning";
$("table tr[class^='a-']").each(function(){
    var current = $(this);
    var currClass = current.attr("class");
    if((current.next().hasClass(currClass)) || current.prev().hasClass(currClass)){
       current.addClass(currClassName);
     } 

    else {
      currClassName = (currClassName == "info") ? "warning" : "info";
     }
   });
```